# Windows Key Press Detection

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

**Question:** Is it possible to monitor for a key press or a certain key press combination like: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>? Something that will allow Windows to execute some code or take action when the keys are pressed.

**I explored** making a shortcut to a batch script and then setting it use shortcut key combinations, but there were issues with it not working when not on the desktop.

**I need it to work:**

- Even when other apps are on foreground, or console is in the background, etc.
- Outside the console window, if other app windows are active on the foreground, so even when console is in the background.

Is there a simple way for Windows to do this with PowerShell or batch without special tools or super complex code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with some of the logic on the [Detecting Key Presses](https://powershell.one/tricks/input-devices/detect-key-press) post, here's a slightly modified variation in a script that when executed it'll monitor for <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`K`</kbd> key presses.

The action this example takes is just writing output to the screen in green, but you can change the action [`Write-Host`] to a different action you need to trigger when those keys are pressed.

> **It will trigger the action. . .**
>
> 1. When you press the <kbd>`K`</kbd> key ***last in the key combination***.
>
>    - Always press and hold down on <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> (or  <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Alt`</kbd>) ***first before you press***
>      <kbd>`K`</kbd>—although [or] ***pressing all three at the same time*** seems to rather consistently trigger.
> 2. On each subsequent press of the keys ***only after the release of all keys used to previously*** trigger an action.
>
>    - Once you press all the keys required to trigger the action, release and don't hold any of them down.
>
> ---
>
> **Other noteworthy items...**
>
> - The `$key` variable value will be "the key" which you'll **press last in the sequence** of the key combination (as referenced as <kbd>`K`</kbd> above) if you find it to work [better] more consistently than all three keys being pressed simultaneously.
> - The variable `$key2` and `$key3` values will always be the ones you **press down and hold before pressing the last** `$key` as referenced as <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> above if you find it to work [better] more consistently than all three keys being pressed simultaneously.

### PowerShell Script

```
$key  = [Byte][Char]'K' ## Letter
$key2 = '0x11' ## Ctrl
$key3 = '0x12' ## Alt 
$Signature = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)] 
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKeyCode); 
'@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name Keyboard -Namespace PsOneApi
do
{   If( [bool]([PsOneApi.Keyboard]::GetAsyncKeyState($key) -eq -32767 -and 
        [PsOneApi.Keyboard]::GetAsyncKeyState($key2) -eq -32767 -and 
        [PsOneApi.Keyboard]::GetAsyncKeyState($key3) -eq -32767))
        { 
            Write-Host "You pressed the combo keys, oh my!!" -ForegroundColor Green 
        }
    
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100

} while($true)
```

### Output (when key combos pressed)

### [image]

### Supporting Resources

- [Detecting Key Presses](https://powershell.one/tricks/input-devices/detect-key-press)
- [GetAsyncKeyState function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)
- [Virtual-Key Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

  - > Use this to find the hex values to plug into the PowerShell `$key[#]` value for special keys where applicable.
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)

Comment: I have a problem. When i am inside a game for example. Otherwise i get message: INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria. Which is response to taskkill command. I wanted keypress to be registered, even when it is not on foreground. Because if program freezes, i won't be likely able to alt+tab! But when i am inside a game, i get nothing. So it seems keypress is not registerered!

Comment: Sure, that line: "Write-Host "You pressed the combo keys, oh my!!" -ForegroundColor Green.". I replaced it with: "taskkill /f /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"". Which is for killing unresponsive programs. When i press your hotkey in Windows: it is responding with: "INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria". But when i am in game, and press it and than i check. There is nothing in console window, so it seems it didn't work. I wanted as i said first: so it works even when other windows are in foreground. If you could please change it so it works like that. Thank you.

Comment: It works in Windows, when i have browser on foreground. But i tried other game and it doesn't work there as well.

Comment: It is steam - pugb, or battle.net sc2. I suppose you updated code, i tested it again and nothing...

Comment: @Moriss5054 ... I updated code to be Alt+Ctrl and then K, but it should still work as it did before with those changes. I just made it so you can press Alt+Ctrl and then K for it to trigger action. Move the variable `$key` values.I'll see what I can dig up on steam.

Comment: It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Oh i didn't see it. I had game mode turned off in the first place. So that' wasn't it!

Comment: Just want to confirm it is working, it saved me from hardreset. Takedown successfully closed unresponsive game on foreground! Thanks again!

Comment: That is awesome, I'm glad I could help you get a solution.