# What is the Windows equivalent of xset command

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, powershell

If on a Ubuntu system I wish to take a peek at different lock keys' state, I can easily run `xset q`.

However, I am not able to find anything similar for Windows system.
I tried Powershell, but it seems to only to tell about `CapsLock` via `[System.Console]::NumberLock` and `NumberLock` via `[System.Console]::NumberLock`.

What I am looking for is the lock status for Function Key(fn).

Comment: The _Fn_ key is not something Windows tracks because it is non-standard.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to verify/demonstrate to others that the function key lock is enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Key Press Detection](https://superuser.com/questions/1578574/windows-key-press-detection)

Comment: That answer is mainly focused on scripts. But I am looking out for a handy command that could give me a quick overview.

Comment: That depends @ReddyLutonadio. I’m afraid there’s no one-size-fits-all solution. Some keyboards may report the _Fn_ key to the computer, others may not (and only report the special functions it triggers).

Answer (score 1):

If you run this in the console:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

... and then press any key, you get a return value that you can extrapolate from.

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# Presses the F1 Key
# Results
<#
VirtualKeyCode Character         ControlKeyState KeyDown
-------------- ---------         --------------- -------
           112          NumLockOn, ScrollLockOn    True
#>
```

I don't have an ***'fn key***' on my keyboard, but, using the above with other special keys, like ***'PrtScn or Pause or other special keys across the top of my MS ergo keyboard'***, returns nothing.

***Update - as per your stated use case***
You can get the state of the function key. I did this on one of my laptops that has fn (fnlk).

Note the response

```
# using just the F1 key fnlk not enabled
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# Results
<#
VirtualKeyCode Character        ControlKeyState KeyDown
-------------- ---------        --------------- -------
        173          NumLockOn, EnhancedKey    True
#>


# using just the F1 key fnlk enabled - Note the difference
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# Results
<#
VirtualKeyCode Character        ControlKeyState KeyDown
-------------- ---------        --------------- -------
        255          NumLockOn, EnhancedKey    True
#>


$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# Results
<#
VirtualKeyCode Character ControlKeyState KeyDown
-------------- --------- --------------- -------
        112                NumLockOn    True
#>


# using fn+F1 - Not fn lock
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# Results
<#
VirtualKeyCode Character ControlKeyState KeyDown
-------------- --------- --------------- -------
        112                NumLockOn    True
#>


# So, this shows, just look at the ControlKeyState and see if the EnhancedKey is set.
If (($Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")).ControlKeyState -match 'EnhancedKey'){'fn key not used or fn lock not enabled'}
```

Comment: I tried it. This helps, but does not really distinguish between function keys pressed by holding down `fn` or without `fn`. It just tells whether a function key is actually pressed.

Comment: Just in case you are curious about the motivation behind this specific use case : Having a way to clearly demonstrate the function key status would prove pretty useful when trying to explain to support executives about a particular shortcut or key binding not working as expected.